# Segmentation fault in C/GMP: calculate factors with Pollard Rho

Tags: c, gmp

I am an experienced programmer, but new to C. I am trying to learn C so I can use the gmp library to write fast big-integer programs; eventually I intend to write the performance parts of my programs in C functions that are called via a foreign function interface from other languages. As a vehicle for learning both C and the gmp library I have written the pollard rho integer factorization program shown below (yes, I know this isn't the best possible implementation of pollard rho, but it is simple, and at the moment I just want to get started). My program compiles correctly but when run it dies with the message "Segmentation fault." I assume that means I've got my pointers messed up somewhere, but I don't see it. Probably more than one. Can someone please look at my program and tell me where I've gone wrong? And point out any style issues or anything else I can improve? Many thanks, Phil

```
/* rho.c -- pollard rho factorization
 * usage: rho n -- prints factors of n then exits
 * compile as gcc -lgmp -o rho rho.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

typedef struct list {
    void *data;
    struct list *next;
} List;

List *insert(void *data, List *next)
{
    List *new;

    if (! (new = malloc(sizeof(List))))
        return NULL;
    new->data = data;
    new->next = next;
    return new;
}

List *insert_in_order(void *x, List *xs)
{
    if (xs == NULL || mpz_cmp(x, xs->data) < 0)
    {
        return insert(x, xs);
    } else {
        List *head = xs;
        while (xs->next != NULL && mpz_cmp(x, xs->next->data) < 0)
        {
            xs = xs->next;
        }
        xs->next = insert(x, xs->next);
        return head;
    }
}

void rho_factor(mpz_t f, mpz_t n, long long unsigned c)
{
    mpz_t t, h, d, r;

    mpz_init_set_ui(t, 2);
    mpz_init_set_ui(h, 2);
    mpz_init_set_ui(d, 1);
    mpz_init_set_ui(r, 0);

    while (mpz_cmp_si(d, 1) == 0)
    {
        mpz_mul(t, t, t);
        mpz_add_ui(t, t, c);
        mpz_mod(t, t, n);

        mpz_mul(h, h, h);
        mpz_add_ui(h, h, c);
        mpz_mod(h, h, n);

        mpz_mul(h, h, h);
        mpz_add_ui(h, h, c);
        mpz_mod(h, h, n);

        mpz_sub(r, t, h);
        mpz_gcd(d, r, n);
    }

    if (mpz_cmp(d, n) == 0)
    {
        rho_factor(f, n, c+1);
    }
    else if (mpz_probab_prime_p(d, 25))
    {
        mpz_set(f, d);
    }
    else
    {
        rho_factor(f, d, c+1);
    }

    mpz_clears(t, h, d, r);
}

void rho_factors(List *fs, mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t f;
    mpz_init_set_ui(f, 0);

    while (! (mpz_probab_prime_p(n, 25)))
    {
        rho_factor(f, n, 1);
        fs = insert_in_order(f, fs);
        mpz_divexact(n, n, f);
    }

    mpz_clear(f);
    insert_in_order(n, fs);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mpz_t f, n;
    mpz_init_set_ui(f, 0);
    List *fs = NULL;

    if (argc<2)
    {
        printf("usage: rho n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    mpz_init_set_str(n, argv[1], 10);

    if (mpz_probab_prime_p(n, 25))
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%s", argv[1]);
    rho_factors(fs, n);
    while (fs != NULL) {
        printf(" %s", mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, fs->data));
        fs = fs->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT1: Thanks to Daniel Fischer, I have made some progress, and am no longer getting a segmentation fault. The code shown below correctly prints the factor 127 when rho_factor is called with n = 1234567, but rho_factors returns a null list, so there is still something wrong with rho_factors. I assume the problem is that I can't keep re-initializing the same variable the way I am doing, but I don't know the right way to do it. Somehow I need to make a copy of each factor that I find, then insert that copy in fs. Many thanks, Phil

```
/* rho.c -- pollard rho factorization
 * usage: rho n -- prints factors of n then exits
 * compile as gcc -lgmp -o rho rho.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

typedef struct list {
    void *data;
    struct list *next;
} List;

List *insert(void *data, List *next)
{
    List *new;

    if (! (new = malloc(sizeof(List))))
        return NULL;
    new->data = data;
    new->next = next;
    return new;

List *insert_in_order(void *x, List *xs)
{
    if (xs == NULL || mpz_cmp(x, xs->data) < 0)
    {
        return insert(x, xs);
    } else {
        List *head = xs;
        while (xs->next != NULL && mpz_cmp(x, xs->next->data) < 0)
        {
            xs = xs->next;
        }
        xs->next = insert(x, xs->next);
        return head;
    }
}

void rho_factor(mpz_t f, mpz_t n, long long unsigned c)
{
    mpz_t t, h, d, r;

    mpz_init_set_ui(t, 2);
    mpz_init_set_ui(h, 2);
    mpz_init_set_ui(d, 1);
    mpz_init_set_ui(r, 0);

    while (mpz_cmp_si(d, 1) == 0)
    {
        mpz_mul(t, t, t);
        mpz_add_ui(t, t, c);
        mpz_mod(t, t, n);

        mpz_mul(h, h, h);
        mpz_add_ui(h, h, c);
        mpz_mod(h, h, n);

        mpz_mul(h, h, h);
        mpz_add_ui(h, h, c);
        mpz_mod(h, h, n);

        mpz_sub(r, t, h);
        mpz_gcd(d, r, n);
    }

    if (mpz_cmp(d, n) == 0)
    {
        rho_factor(f, n, c+1);
    }
    else if (mpz_probab_prime_p(d, 25))
    {
        mpz_set(f, d);
    }
    else
    {
        rho_factor(f, d, c+1);
    }

    mpz_clears(t, h, d, r, NULL);
}

void rho_factors(List *fs, mpz_t n)
{
    while (! (mpz_probab_prime_p(n, 25)))
    {
        mpz_t f;
        mpz_init_set_ui(f, 0);

        rho_factor(f, n, 1);
        fs = insert_in_order(f, fs);
        mpz_divexact(n, n, f);
    }

    insert_in_order(n, fs);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mpz_t f, n;
    mpz_init_set_ui(f, 0);
    List *fs = NULL;

    if (argc<2)
    {
        printf("usage: rho n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    mpz_init_set_str(n, argv[1], 10);

    if (mpz_probab_prime_p(n, 25))
    {
        printf("%s is prime\n", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

    rho_factor(f, n, 1);
    printf("%s\n", mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, f));

    printf("%s", argv[1]);
    rho_factors(fs, n);
    while (fs != NULL) {
        printf(" %s", mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, fs->data));
        fs = fs->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2: Got it. Thanks to Daniel Fischer. Final version shown below.

```
/* rho.c -- pollard rho factorization
 * usage: rho n -- prints factors of n then exits
 * compile as gcc -lgmp -o rho rho.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

typedef struct list {
    void *data;
    struct list *next;
} List;

List *insert(void *data, List *next)
{
    List *new;

    new = malloc(sizeof(List));
    new->data = data;
    new->next = next;
    return new;
}

List *insert_in_order(void *x, List *xs)
{
    if (xs == NULL || mpz_cmp(x, xs->data) < 0)
    {
        return insert(x, xs);
    }
    else
    {
        List *head = xs;
        while (xs->next != NULL && mpz_cmp(x, xs->next->data) < 0)
        {
            xs = xs->next;
        }
        xs->next = insert(x, xs->next);
        return head;
    }
}

void rho_factor(mpz_t f, mpz_t n, long long unsigned c)
{
    mpz_t t, h, d, r;

    mpz_init_set_ui(t, 2);
    mpz_init_set_ui(h, 2);
    mpz_init_set_ui(d, 1);
    mpz_init_set_ui(r, 0);

    while (mpz_cmp_si(d, 1) == 0)
    {
        mpz_mul(t, t, t);
        mpz_add_ui(t, t, c);
        mpz_mod(t, t, n);

        mpz_mul(h, h, h);
        mpz_add_ui(h, h, c);
        mpz_mod(h, h, n);

        mpz_mul(h, h, h);
        mpz_add_ui(h, h, c);
        mpz_mod(h, h, n);

        mpz_sub(r, t, h);
        mpz_gcd(d, r, n);
    }

    if (mpz_cmp(d, n) == 0)
    {
        rho_factor(f, n, c+1);
    }
    else if (mpz_probab_prime_p(d, 25))
    {
        mpz_set(f, d);
    }
    else
    {
        rho_factor(f, d, c+1);
    }

    mpz_clears(t, h, d, r, NULL);
}

void rho_factors(List **fs, mpz_t n)
{
    while (! (mpz_probab_prime_p(n, 25)))
    {
        mpz_t *f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
        mpz_init_set_ui(*f, 0);

        rho_factor(*f, n, 1);
        *fs = insert_in_order(*f, *fs);
        mpz_divexact(n, n, *f);
    }

    *fs = insert_in_order(n, *fs);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mpz_t f, n;
    mpz_init_set_ui(f, 0);
    List *fs = NULL;

    if (argc<2)
    {
        printf("usage: rho n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    mpz_init_set_str(n, argv[1], 10);

    if (mpz_probab_prime_p(n, 25))
    {
        printf("%s is prime\n", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Factors of %s:", argv[1]);
    rho_factors(&fs, n);
    while (fs != NULL) {
        printf(" %s", mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, fs->data));
        fs = fs->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug your program with [gdb](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/#2.2). It's much easier to fix those kinds of bugs if you know where it happens.

Comment: Banthar: I haven't yet learned to use gdb.

Comment: Geting backtrace is pretty simple just run [those commands](https://gist.github.com/1866512).

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with Banthar--this is just the first issue you're running into, but there will be many more. It's worth the investment, many times over, to learn how to use a good debugger.

Comment: I intend to. But I can't learn everything at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reuse an `mpz_t` like that:

```
void rho_factors(List *fs, mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t f;
    mpz_init_set_ui(f, 0);

    while (! (mpz_probab_prime_p(n, 25)))
    {
        rho_factor(f, n, 1);
        fs = insert_in_order(f, fs);
        mpz_divexact(n, n, f);
    }

    mpz_clear(f);
    insert_in_order(n, fs);
}
```

When GMP reallocates the storage pointed to via `f`, the old storage is `free`d. That may well happen in the while loop, but not necessarily. If it doesn't, all list entries point to the same number, however.

But after the loop, when you `mpz_clear(f)`, every `data` pointer in the list `fs` has become a wild pointer, and when you then `insert_in_order(n, fs)`, you dereference previously `free`d pointers. (That very probably happens already during some insert in the while loop, but here it is guaranteed.)

Also, in `rho_factor`, you should call

```
mpz_clears(t, h, d, r, NULL);
```

the argument list to `mpz_clears` must be `NULL`-terminated.

Further problems:

- You pass a `List *`, so the changes made to `fs` in `rho_factors`  don't affect the `fs` in `main`. Pass a `List **` and dereference it where appropriate, also you forgot to assign the final `insert_in_order`'s returned value.
- The local variable `f` goes out of scope at the end of the block, leading to corruption. `malloc` pointers to `mpz_t` to keep them alive.

  void rho_factors(List **fs, mpz_t n)
  {
      while (! (mpz_probab_prime_p(n, 25)))
      {
          mpz_t *f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
          mpz_init_set_ui(*f, 0);

  ```
      rho_factor(*f, n, 1);
      *fs = insert_in_order(*f, *fs);
      mpz_divexact(n, n, *f);
  }

  *fs = insert_in_order(n, *fs);
  ```

  }

and in `main`

```
List *fs = NULL;
/* snip */
rho_factors(&fs, n);
```

should do it. Finally (?), you have a glitch in `insert_in_order`, the comparison in the while loop is backwards.

Comment: So the answer is to move the two lines that create and initialize f from the top of the function to inside the loop, thus using a new f each time, and remove the clear at the end of the loop. I did that, but still get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes, `mpz_clears` needs a NULL-terminated argument list, overlooked that.

Comment: Progress. No longer getting a segmentation fault, and rho_factor works properly. But rho_factors still doesn't. See EDIT1 for details.